# Jquery and CoffeeScript scrollTo with Rails and Haml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml

I'm trying to perform a really simple task with `CoffeeScript` `Rails` and `Haml`. I havn't used `CoffeeScript` that much, but I want to give it a try.

When the user presses a button I want the view to scroll to a certain div id. In the top of my page I have an Id like this:

```
#area_1
```

My links looks like this:

```
= link_to "Area", "#", id: "area_button_1"
```

In my automatically generated `CoffeScript` file I have a function that looks like this:

```
$ ->
  scrollToArea = (button, area) ->
    $(button).click ->
      scrollTo(area, 800)
```

I try to call this method in one of my view files like this:

```
:javascript
  scrollToArea("#area_button_1", "#area_1")
```

But this isn't working. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a scoping problem. `$ ->` is a function call like:

```
$(function() { ...
});
```

and CoffeeScript automatically [scopes your variables to their function](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope) so your CoffeeScript becomes JavaScript like this:

```
$(function() {
  var scrollToArea = function(button, area) { ... };
});
```

There's also another self-executing function wrapper around the whole thing (unless you [compile with `-b`](http://coffeescript.org/#usage)) to prevent scope creep.

You don't even need the `$ ->` here, that code just defines a function so it can run any time, you don't need to wait until the DOM is ready. You'll also want to push your `scrollToArea` function into the global namespace if you want to use it elsewhere. The result would look like:

```
window.scrollToArea = (button, area) ->
  $(button).click ->
    scrollTo(area, 800)
```

or:

```
# `this` is `window` in this context so `@x` is the same as `window.x`
@scrollToArea = (button, area) ->
  $(button).click ->
    scrollTo(area, 800)
```

You'll probably want a `$()` wrapper where you use `scollToArea` as well, you probably don't want to call `scrollToArea` until the DOM is ready:

```
:javascript
  $(function() { scrollToArea("#area_button_1", "#area_1") )
```

I'm not a HAML guy so hopefully I haven't butchered the syntax.

Comment: Thanks, scrollTo doesn't seem to work as Roy pointed out (if I don't get the plugin). How would you translate this to `CoffeeScript`: `$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$("#area_3").offset().top}, 'fast');`?

Comment: @Anders: Drop the semicolon and you're done (or leave the semicolon in and you're done). Or you could do something like this:http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24(%22html%2C%20body%22).animate(%0A%20%20scrollTop%3A%20%24(%22%23area_3%22).offset().top%0A%20%20'fast'%0A)

Comment: I asked another (unrelated) CoffeeScript question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292183/coffeescript-detect-if-current-scroll-position-is-below-div. Take a look if you want, seems like you know what you are doing. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with coffeeScript, but here's the jQuery to accomplish this, hopefully it should be straightforward to translate.

What this does is make the `scrollTop` of the window equal to the top `offset()` position of the target element.

```
<a href="#button" class="scroll-trigger">Go to button</a>
```

```js
$('.scroll-trigger').click(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($(this).attr('href')).offset().top);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2zyD/3/)

---

If you want to animate the scrolling, use this:

```
$('.scroll-trigger').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($el.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2zyD/2/)

Comment: Thanks, It is mostly the translation part that I'm currently struggling with. Or possible something I have missed related to Rails or Haml. Whats the difference between `scrollTop` and `scrollTo`? `scrollTo` seems simpler...

Comment: You must be using a plugin for that, as there is only [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) in plain jQuery.