# CoffeeScript - detect if current scroll position is below div

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I would like to detect when the user scrolls past a certain point in the window.

```
[Meta]
X
scroll below = alert()
```

I'm quite new to CoffeeScript, so any  help would be great!

What I currently have is this:

```
$("#area_1").bind('scroll', ->
  scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).outerHeight()
  divTotalHeight = $(this)[0].scrollHeight()
  if (scrollPosition >= divTotalHeight)
    alert('end reached')
  )
```

And no alert is showing up. Any tips?

**Update**
I suspect that my problem have to do with my two variables. Here is an example:

```
$("#area_1").bind($(window).scroll ->
  alert('before 1') # Gets called
  scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).outerHeight()
  divTotalHeight = $(this)[0].scrollHeight()
  alert('before 2') # Never gets called
  if (1 == 1)
    alert('should get called but dosn't')
)
```

Comment: The coffeescript part seems OK, did you try printing out scrollPosition and divTotalHeight or setting a breakpoint there?

Comment: Does `#area_1` scroll or does the whole `window`?

Comment: @muistooshort the whole window. So when X (in the question) gets "invisible" then I want the alert. Or it could also be when another div below X becomes visible, if thats easier.

Comment: @Anders, do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Have you tried binding to `$(window).scroll ->` instead?

Comment: @muistooshort It seems like the code inside the if statement never gets called for some reason. I did bind to `$(window).scroll ->` instead, added an `alert` message before the if statement. That gets called. But even if I make sure that the condition in the if statement is true `(1 == 1)`, the code inside never gets called.

Comment: @Dogbert, yes. No error what I can see.

Comment: I have added an update to my question.

Comment: I meant `$(window).scroll -> ...` instead of `$('#area_1').bind('scroll', -> ...`. And [`scrollHeight` is a property, not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6853354/479863).

Comment: @muistooshort Got it to work using `$(window).scroll ->` instead.